# CFSocket created in Swift not listening

Tags: swift, macos, sockets, swift2, foundation

I'm trying to get basic Bonjour discovery up and running using the sample code from [a 2012 WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-707/), but having converted it to Swift. It's partially working. I am able to register a port, and register my service on that port. The client is able to discover that service, and resolve it.

Here's the issue: I call `CFSocketCreateWithNative()` and specify the callback listener, but that callback never gets called. Further, I tried connecting wiht telnet (`telnet localhost 12345`) and I get:

> Trying ::1...
>
> telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
>
> Trying fe80::1...
>
> telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
>
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

This is an abbreviated version of how I'm registering the sockets, with the full Swift file [in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/abbeycode/b97801aa424495215f93/e91fda8aaf76e554336a1f30561a393aac467ff2):

```
private func registerIPv4Socket() throws -> (Int32, in_port_t) {
    let fd4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

    var sin = sockaddr_in()
    sin.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    sin.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(sin))
    sin.sin_port = 0

    withUnsafePointer(&sin) {
        Foundation.bind(fd4, UnsafePointer($0), UInt32(sin.sin_len))
    }

    var addrLen = socklen_t(sizeofValue(sin))
    withUnsafeMutablePointers(&sin, &addrLen) { (sinPtr, addrPtr) -> Int32 in
        getsockname(fd4, UnsafeMutablePointer(sinPtr), UnsafeMutablePointer(addrPtr))
    }

    let listenError = listen(fd4, 5)        
    return (fd4, sin.sin_port)
}

private func registerIPv6Socket(port: in_port_t) throws -> Int32 {
    let fd6 = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

    var one: Int32 = 1
    withUnsafePointer(&one) {
        setsockopt(fd6, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, UnsafePointer($0), socklen_t(sizeofValue(one)))
    }

    var sin6 = sockaddr_in6()
    sin6.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)
    sin6.sin6_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(sin6))
    sin6.sin6_port = port

    withUnsafePointer(&sin6) {
        Foundation.bind(fd6, UnsafePointer($0), UInt32(sin6.sin6_len))
    }

    var addrLen = socklen_t(sizeofValue(sin6))
    withUnsafeMutablePointers(&sin6, &addrLen) { (sinPtr, addrPtr) -> Int32 in
        getsockname(fd6, UnsafeMutablePointer(sinPtr), UnsafeMutablePointer(addrPtr))
    }

    listen(fd6, 5)
    return fd6
}
```

Why isn't my app listening on the port it's reporting it should be?

Comment: did you create a socket, set the options, than bind and finally  listen ? you can register and publish via bonjour without running service, you can run your service without that bonjour megaphone. you can check with telnet if your socket is listening or not. the most important part of your code is missing. how did you managed create, configure, bind and listen ...

Comment: @user3441734 Good call on testing with telnet. My connection is refused. I updated the question with the telnet output, and I also posted a Gist (https://gist.github.com/abbeycode/b97801aa424495215f93) with all of the code.

Comment: i checked the gist. some trouble was clear for me on first sight, even thought that part of code works like a charm ... your style is different from mine, give me a time to check it. what i can see right now, is missing SO_REUSEPORT option. still at least first connection request should work. your app is osx or ios?

Comment: @user3441734 The server side of the connection is OS X. The client side will be iOS/tvOS.

Comment: check you port number. it should be in bigendian order ... like this ... sin6.sin6_port = port.bigEndian

Comment: @user3441734 I had tried that at one point. Which method of mine needs it flipped, and what function in Swift should I be using? There seemed to be multiple options.

Comment: if you read from address....  structures address and port are in bigendian. if you write there you have to write in bigendian. that is generally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94742/discussion-between-user3441734-and-dov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IPv4 socket is listening on port `sin.sin_port.bigEndian`, but your IPv6 socket is listening on the little endian port. Update your IPv6 code to use the big endian port:

```
sin.sin6_port = port.bigEndian
```